# where and how to find info about airdropped tokens on phantom

Tags: token, phantom-wallet

Where or how can I find out about a random coin that was deposited into my phantom account. I am very worried abouy it being a scam. It's called Lushcoin and was just dropped. Just wanna be sure.

Answer (score 2):

You can view the token on Solscan by clicking in the top right corner when viewing the token in Phantom.  From there, you can see how people are interacting with it. If you see loads of burns, it's probably a scam. Or you can do more research on the token from the Solscan page.